# Mapping groups of Checkbox values to input fields using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I have multiple groups of checkboxes which I wish to copy the values into a text field for each respective group of checkboxes.

I had found a good answer previously (below), however this only seems to work for ALL checkboxes in the form, when I want to get the values in groups. I have tried applying this method by also assigning custom classes to the groups of checkboxes so I can capture them individually, but have not had any success.

**WORKING CODE**

```
$checks = $(":checkbox");
    $checks.on('change', function () {
        var string = $checks.filter(":checked").map(function(i,v){
            return this.value;
        }).get().join(", ");
        $('#testField').val(string);
    });
```

**HAVE TRIED w/ no luck**

```
$checks = $(".customClass");
    $checks.on('change', function () {
        var string = $checks.filter(":checked").map(function(i,v){
            return this.value;
        }).get().join(", ");
        $('#testField').val(string);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `$('.customClass:checked').get().map(e => e.value).join(', ')` :

- `$('.customClass:checked')` gets every checked checkbox
- `.get()` gets the `NodeList` from your jQuery object list
- `.map(e => e.value)` transforms your `NodeList` into a list of values
- `.join(', ')` joins the values in a `String`

```js
$('.customClass').on('change', () => {
  $('#testField').val($('.customClass:checked').get().map(e => e.value).join(', '));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="customClass" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" class="customClass" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" class="customClass" value="3">
<input type="checkbox" class="customClass" value="4">

<input type="text" id="testField">
```

Comment: Awesome. Didn't know you could do `.customClass:checked`. Thanks.